# Android Swipe layout above fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, swipe

I want to do the following:[image: question]

I have a fragment where I want to add a Button/imageview. If I drag the button up it will show another layout with 2 buttons on. When the layout is on top it is also possible to swipe the layout down again. Also an important thing is that the underlying layout can't be hidden because i want to create a blurred effect above this one.

Now the problem is that I don't know how to begin with this? Is there a way to make a part of a layout invisible and make it visible while swiping up? Should I work with gestures or?

Comment: If I have understood it properly you want to hide portion of a layout? if that is the case you can divide the children of layout and place them layouts and in turn place these two layouts in another layout which will act as parent. Hide the desired child layout by setting its visibility "gone".

Comment: @Badrul In fact I don't want to hide the underlying layout because i want to blur that layout, i'll add it in the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use [umano panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) (Open Source) to achieve that effect.